# Istio remote error: tls: error decrypting message

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, istio, kubernetes-pod

I am starting out with Istio and trying to enable TLS on north-south traffic by creating a gateway resource enabled with TLS and am following this doco https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/secure-ingress-mount/.

I have following everything to the dot but I keep getting this error from the Istiod pod logs:

```
2020-05-21T04:41:44.467181Z info    grpc: Server.Serve failed to complete security handshake from "10.x.x.x:34774": remote error: tls: bad certificate
2020-05-21T04:41:54.416502Z info    grpc: Server.Serve failed to complete security handshake from "10.x.x.x:56768": remote error: tls: error decrypting message
2020-05-21T04:42:00.305269Z info    grpc: Server.Serve failed to complete security handshake from "10.x.x.x:56834": remote error: tls: error decrypting message
```

Any idea why this is happening? I did check for typos while creating certs but cannot find any.

This works for when I disable TLS and use HTTP. So I am assuming that the error is from using the certificates and the logs tell the same thing too.

Details about the cluster:

> AWS EKS Version: 1.14
>
> Istio Version: 1.51

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, Can You verify if `istiod` pod is running? You can verify that with `kubectl -n istio-system get pod -lapp=istiod`.

Comment: Hello @PiotrMalec the above logs are from Istiod pod. All pods are running.

Comment: Try deleting the `istio-galley` pod and allowing it to be recreated. Maybe it can fix certificate issue.